# How does one close a dependent container with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two containers that are spun up using docker-compose:

```
web:
  image: personal/webserver
  depends_on:
    - database
  entrypoint: /usr/bin/runmytests.sh
database:
  image: personal/database
```

In this example, runmytests.sh is a script that runs for a few seconds, then returns with either a zero or non-zero exit code.

When I run this setup with docker-compose, `web_1` runs the script and exits.  `database_1` remains open, because the process running the database is still running.

I'd like to trigger a graceful exit on database_1 when web_1's tasks have been completed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass the `--abort-on-container-exit` flag to `docker-compose up` to have the other containers stop when one exits.

Comment: There's always a CLI option I'm forgetting to these commands, so many possibilities. Great answer, and this deserves to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing is called a Pod in Kubernetes or a Task in AWS. It's a grouping of containers that form a unit. Docker doesn't have that notion currently (Swarm mode has "tasks" which come close but they only support one container per task at this point).

There is a hacky workaround beside scripting it as @BMitch described. You could mount the Docker daemon socket from the host. Eg:

```
web:
  image: personal/webserver
  depends_on:
    - database
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  entrypoint: /usr/bin/runmytests.sh
```

and add the Docker client to your `personal/webserver` image. That would allow your runmytests.sh script to use the Docker CLI to shut down the database first. Eg: `docker kill database`.

**Edit:**
Third option. If you want to stop **all** containers when one fails, you can use the `--abort-on-container-exit` option to `docker-compose` as @dnephin mentions in another answer.

Comment: This seems like it's a lot more involved then it needs to be. You can just pass the `--abort-on-container-exit` flag to `docker-compose up` to have the other containers stop.

Comment: @dnephin You're correct in this case (ie: all other containers are to be stopped). I always think of the docker compose file that people post in SO as a simplified, reduced version of their real compose file where one has multiple services defined.  I'll add this info to my answer.

Comment: Mounting the docker socket should be considered a last resort for containers, it's only needed for containers that administer other containers. Using this for a script that runs a database would be overkill. Any container with this socket mounted is giving full root access to any commands running in that container to the host machine and any containers it's running.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe docker-compose supports this use case. However, making a simple shell script would easily resolve this:

```
#!/bin/sh

docker run -d --name=database personal/database
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=/usr/bin/runmytests.sh personal/webserver
docker stop database
docker rm database
```